# Can $A_\mu (\bar{e}_R\gamma^\mu e_R)$ operator give $e^+_Le^-_R \gamma$ vertex

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams

In short-can this operator have a $e^+_L e^-_R\to e^+_L e^-_R$ type process? If so, how? There is no $e_L$ here. I suppose this has something to do with the fact that $v_L=u_R$ in terms of weyl spinors(so I can replace incoming fermion with outgoing antifermion of opposite helicity), but I would like to understand this more precisely.

I wish to understand what processes $A_\mu(\bar{e}_R\gamma^\mu e_R)$ mediate. I was under the impression that it will mediate right handed bhabha type scattering $e^+_R e^-_R\to e^+ _R e^-_R$, or right and left handed Moller type scattering $e^-_R e^-_R\to e^-_R e^-_R$. But in spinor helicity notation, the kind of vertex in this last process is similar to what one might have in $L$-positron $R$-electron annihilation. So I was wondering if this process can indeed occur here, and if so, why EXACTLY. I have mentioned my vague inkling above, and I can talk in terms of creating destruction of antiparticles and particles but I wish to have a clear understanding. Perhaps thinking in terms of a projection operator inserted in the usual QED interaction will help.

Comment: Any chance of wording this in a way people can understand it?

Comment: @Oбжорoв can you tell me what should I make clear? Feel free to edit the question :)